# How can I have my Google Assistant and Home devices play an MP3 in response to voice command?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

I want to have my Google Assistant and Home devices (and Mini) respond to a voice command by playing an MP3 file. How can I do this?

Comment: What's your goal, they'll react to properly used audio stimulation....

Answer (score 5):

Google  Assistant's **Actions** can return a subset of [SSML](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/), part of which allows you to instruct the device to play an audio file such as an MP3. An example is given of the SSML to use in the [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/ssml) documentation; I've adapted it below for reference:

```xml
<speak>
  Here is an MP3 file.
  <audio src="https://www.example.com/MY_MP3_FILE.mp3">didn't get your MP3 audio file</audio>.
</speak>
```

This requires you to be developing an [Action](https://developers.google.com/actions/extending-the-assistant) — the entire process is a little more complex than that, and more detailed information is available directly from Google. If you aren't interested in that, and just want a simple home solution, read on.

---

You could alternatively [upload your MP3 to Google Play Music](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7030379?hl=en-GB), then use a [shortcut](https://support.google.com/googlehome/answer/7382893?hl=en-GB) to map whatever phrase you want to "Play [file name] from my library".

Shortcuts can be configured from the Google Home app, as follows:

- Menu > More Settings > Shortcuts > Add
- Under 'When I say Ok Google', enter your desired phrase
- Under 'Google Assistant should do', type 'Play [file name] from my library' *after uploading your file to Google Play Music*. It's possible that you might need a paid subscription to do this; try it first and see.
- Save your shortcut, and give it a try.